# Receive image in JavaScript from Java REST server sending mediaType octet stream

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, image, rest

I am pretty new to REST and have got all the basic to work with sending JSON, but I am having problem with images. I have saved the images in a folder on my server sending a form request to my REST API in Java. Now I want to show some selected images in a  in JavaScript/HTML.

My code in Java:

```
@Path("/getImages")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getImage(int id){

    File file = new File("FileLocation");
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+file.getName() + "\"")
            .build();
}
```

I try to get it with an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url',
    data: JSON.stringify(id12),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'image/*',
    },
    success: function (response) {

     //dont know what to do with the response here to get it into a <img>

    },
});
```